# Achieving a Successful Post()

Tags: angular, rest, http

I'm building an Angular2+ app with .NET RESTful API. Once I click save after adding my recipe items, I'm getting an error message in the console. It seems to not be Post()'ing correctly.

**Add-Recipe Component (.html)**

```
<h1>Add a Recipe</h1>
<form class="form-inline">
    <label class="sr-only" for="recipeTitle">Recipes</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipeTitle" name="recipeTitle" placeholder="Recipe Title" [(ngModel)]="title">
    </div>

    <label class="sr-only" for="count">Ingredient</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="count" name="count" placeholder="Count" [(ngModel)]="count">

    <label class="sr-only" for="ingredient">Recipes</label>
    <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ingredient" name="ingredient" placeholder="Ingredient" [(ngModel)]="ingredient">
    </div>
    <p>the count: {{ itemCount }}</p>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" value="Add" (click)="addIngredient()">
  </form>
  <h2>My Ingredients</h2>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredientsArray">
          <span class="badge">{{ ingredient.count }}</span> {{ ingredient.ingredient }}

      </li>
    </ul>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveRecipe()">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
```

**Add Recipe Code Behind**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-recipe',
  templateUrl: './add-recipe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-recipe.component.css']
})
export class AddRecipeComponent implements OnInit {
  itemCount: number;
  count: number;
  ingredient: string = '';
  title: string = '';
  ingredientsArray = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.itemCount = this.ingredientsArray.length;
  }

  addIngredient() {
    this.ingredientsArray.push({ count: this.count, ingredient: this.ingredient });
    this.ingredient = '';
    this.itemCount = this.ingredientsArray.length;
    this.count = null;
  }

  saveRecipe() {
    this.http.post('api/recipes', 
      { title: this.title, ingredients: this.ingredientsArray, itemCount: this.itemCount })
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        console.log('should be saved');

      });
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(string title, List<IngredientsController> ingredients)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

It seems like everything is set up the way it's supposed to be but I'm getting a huge error in the console like it's not reaching. The Error Message says

> message: "Http failure response for
>   https://localhost:5001/api/recipes: 404 Not Found"

**ingredients.ts**

```
export class Ingredient {
    count: number;
    ingredient: string;
  }
```

Am I haven't to create a page? Do I need to create some kind of component that routes to that url?

Comment: Are you sure that endpoint exists?  That's what the 404 is describing to you.

Comment: I see nothing in what you posted that indicates you've got a server route there, it's almost all front-end code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple points of error are here

1) With Http Post, all the parameters have to go as a "single" payload. Hence you need to create a dedicated class for every type of payload in your application, and construct a JSON in the client code to match it. For example, in this case your class will be as follows:-

```
public class Input
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    /* Your code refers this to IngredientsController list, 
     * However it should be Ingrediends as you don't intend to create a list of actual controllers. 
     * Please check*/
    public List<Ingredients> Ingredients { get; set; }

    public int ItemCount { get; set; }
}
```

Usually the casing defaults to camel case while using JSON, but you can force it to be pascal case if you want by changing the formatter (just to ensure you end up correct JSON field names)

2) The Url you are using is "api/recipies" but in your route, you may have missed decorating the url via RouteName or RoutePrefix (if this is attribute based routing). If this is convention based routing, make sure your server side controller name is "Recipes" as any difference will fail in the route.
(Are you able to make any calls to the controller, by the way?

3) Don't worry about the "https" vs "http", it is due to the fact that you have a server certificate installed and used (ng serve --ssl command) and hence the angular http module is using https instead of http.

If this does't helps, please post your controller code (just remove private and other methods) and any other errors you get.

Comment: 1) I added the ingredients.ts file. Isn't that what you're referring to? 
You're right about the List<>. I didn't catch that. I'm trying to add a different type but the intellisense seems to be wanting to add _IngredientsController_. How can I get it to be of type ingredients?

Comment: Check the path to the ingredients file import. Also you need to setup the class for input payload

Comment: Done and done. I had the wrong url, like you said and. I set up two classes in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

404 status code usually indicates that the url you're trying to hit is not found and the issue is not on server side it's on client side. The route you're trying to hit is https://localhost:5001/api/recipes, I do not think the localhost should have https as protocol, localhost should be http. So because of this the localhost is not found, you should change it to http://localhost:5001/api/recipes. Let me know if that works for you.